# Parallel operation with 'if' condition

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am working on preparing my own functions that will work on pretty big databases. I can see they are slow when there are built in loops so I am trying to avoid them. This one so far I don't know how to avoid:
I want to prepare a vector, which is made out of two other vectors in a way that depends on their components. Here is an example:

```
v1 <- 1:11
v2 <- 11:1

v3 <- vector()

for (i in 1:11){

       if(v1[i] < v2[i]){

               v3[i] <- v1[i] + v2[i]

       }else if(v1[i] > v2[i]){

               v3[i] <- v1[i] - v2[i]
       }else{

               v3[i] <- NA

       }

}
```

Can you please explain me how to create v3 without a loop? The function shall eventually work with much more complex if-else statements (ladder and built-in ones).
Thanks!

Comment: Curious what "pretty big" means here. You might want a different approach for 1 million rows than for 100 million rows, for instance.

Comment: True! Data will not exceed 1 million rows. Usually 10 000 - 20 000. Max 200 000 - 300 000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v3 <- v1 + ifelse(v1<v2, v2, ifelse(v1>v2, -v2, NA))

[1] 12 12 12 12 12 NA  2  4  6  8 10
```

or if you have multiple cases, I think the `dplyr::case_when` syntax is cleaner than lots of nested ifelse's.

```
v3 <- dplyr::case_when(
  v1<v2   ~  v1+v2,
  v1>v2   ~  v1-v2,
  TRUE    ~  NA_integer_    # note dplyr::case_when and dplyr::if_else are
)                           # strict about types and require the output
                            # alternatives to be the same type
```

Either way, these are vectorized operations, which means R doesn't need to translate into low-level code with each loop, and should be more efficient.

Comment: Looks neat! Thank you!

Comment: btw, here's my favorite explanation of vectorization in R and why it makes a big difference in performance: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/